# In the Linux function blk_mq_rq_to_pdu what is a pdu?

Tags: linux, device-driver

I am writing a block device driver and having been copying parts of another one. They use the function blk_mq_rq_to_pdu, but I dont really understand what it does. It seems to just return a void pointer. What exactly is a PDU in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

PDU is not Linux-specific. It's a Protocol Data Unit. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit)

> In telecommunications, a protocol data unit (PDU) is a single unit of information transmitted among peer entities of a computer network. A PDU is composed of protocol-specific control information and user data. In the layered architectures of communication protocol stacks, each layer implements protocols tailored to the specific type or mode of data exchange.

So in device drivers, this is a generic term for whatever units of data are managed by the specific device or protocol.